# How to convert unit of time to Centiseconds in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I am working with Excel and I need to convert a time unit like this mm:ss.00 (centiseconds) all to centiseconds. 
There are some formulas to extract Minutes and Seconds from this format but I dont know how can I have all in sentiseconds!

For example, if we have a time unit 02:02.18 it should return us 6218 centiseconds! but how? :( with which formula or macro?!

Thanks in advance,

Sama

Comment: Do you know what "multiplication" and "addition" are?

Comment: No! only you are the only one who knows what they are!

Answer (score 2):

The formula you need to you is of the form

```
=(A1/"0:0:1")*100
```

**Explanation**: Essentially we are dividing a time by one second, converting it to seconds, and then multiplying it by 100 to get the centiseconds.

Note: Make sure the format of your column is a number if the result doesn't work. `A1` is just a placeholder for whatever cell you want to use. Also I believe your [conversion is wrong](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%20mintues%202.18%20seconds%20into%20centiseconds).

#### If the excel SECOND function returned a floating-point number:

Generally, if you know how to extract minutes and seconds, creating a formula is very straight forward. You know there are 60 seconds in a minute and 100 centiseconds in a second, the total number of centiseconds should be

```
 =MINUTE(A1)*6000 + SECOND(A1)*100
```

However the excel `SECOND()` function only returns integers, and there are no functions that return smaller time steps, so it does not work this way.

Answer (score 1):

peanut_butter's answer works for me...but you can also do it this way

`=A1*8640000`

format result cell as number or general

That works because excel's default "unit" is the day - you want the number of "centiseconds" and there are 8640000 of those in one day (24*60*60*100)